# How do I add descriptions to Google Forms checklist items?

Tags: google-forms

How can I add a description to each checkbox item in Google Forms?

Answer (score 2):

Where it shows "Option 1" overwrite with text of your choice, and so on for any others:

[image: Checkbox example]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add description to individual checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in parenthesis after your check list item. If you are trying to add a description to just the question, you click the three dots on the bottom right and click description